# Azure EventHubs: recommended values for PartitionManagerOptions

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Are there any guidelines on setting values for the parameters in  PartitionManagerOptions?, specifically:

- AcquireInterval: 10 secs (def value)
- RenewInterval: 10 secs  (def value)
- LeaseInterval: 30 secs  (def value)

I am concerned that if the processing of a batch of messages take longer than these values then I could face issues when the expired leases..
Unfortunately there is not much documentation on these parameters.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the lease management runs on different thread than the batch processing thread.

The intervals you mentioned affect how fast can partitions be evenly distributed between event processors and are not affected by batch processing time.

Remember that if your batch for example took some time(let's say 10 minutes) and other event processor in this time will take over the partition( by taking over blob lease), when your batch process will try to use the "Checkout" method after it finished processing, it will throw an error since the blob where the checkout data is at, is not held by the current event processor.